# chroot() and mkdir() permissions

Tags: c, directory, root, mkdir

My C program needs to be executed as system root, because of a necessary `chroot()` system call.

During program execution, I need to call some `mkdir()`, and the resulting new directories seem to be accessible only by root, as expected.

How can I use `mkdir()` to create new directories accessible by every user, although the program execution as system root?

Comment: `chmod()` on the created directory?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568681/using-chmod-in-a-c-program

Comment: Since my program needs root rights only for the chroot system call, I'd like to not need to execute it with sudo. So, I think i need to change the process capability, but...how?

Comment: So,myabe I can use the setcap command into the Makefile for the command. The problem is that, although used sudo setcap "cap_sys_chroot=p" myprogram, the chroot exits with errno EPERM

Comment: Solved adding into the Makefile the command: setcap "cap_sys_chroot=+pe" myprog